# Can't load view.jsp using Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, view

I'm new in Spring MVC and try to make an exercise, like in the example. I have index.jsp and view.jsp. Index.jsp is loaded well, but when I try load view.jsp, it teturns empty field and logger doesnt show me any mistake. I use IntellijIDEA. Below all classes and files, let me know, if i have to give other info. Thanks.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.form</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans       
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
   ">

<context:component-scan base-package="controllers"/>

<bean id="vievResolver" class ="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

<bean id="HttpGatewayInit" class ="controllers.HttpGatewayInit">
</bean>

<bean name="shape" class="shapes.Rectangle">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value ="12" />
    <constructor-arg index="1" value ="2" />
</bean>

<bean name="circle" class="shapes.Circle">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value ="8" />
</bean>

<bean name="rectanglepoint" class="shapes.RectanglePoint">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref ="leftend" />
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref ="rightend" />
</bean>

<bean name="leftend" class="shapes.Point">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value ="4" />
    <constructor-arg index="1" value ="3" />
</bean>

<bean name="rightend" class="shapes.Point">
    <property name="x" value ="12" />
    <property name="y" value ="8" />
</bean>
```

Controller (System.out.println(shape.square()) shows me, that mapping do work)

```
package controllers;

import org.springframework.asm.Attribute;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;
import shapes.Shape;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;


@Controller
public class MainController {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("shape")
private Shape shape;

public MainController(){
}

@RequestMapping (value="/shape.form",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView main(){
    /*class HttpGatewayInit implements WebApplicationInitializer {
        @Override
        public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

        }
    }*/

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("view");
    modelAndView.addObject("message", shape.square());
    System.out.println(shape.square());


    return modelAndView;

}
}
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>$Title$</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <a href = "shape.form">Next page</a>
 </body>
</html>
```

view.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>View</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <span>${message}</span>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You mean span here I guess? <spun>${message}</spun>. Change it to <span>${message}</span> or <p>${message}</p>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check import

```
import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;
```

I tried changing it to `import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;`
 and it worked for me.

Comment: Man, you'r my best! It work for me too. IDE've proposed me 2 variants for import, and i mechanically chose incorrect.

Comment: It's my first post on stackoverflow, i don't know how to mark, that it is wright answer and improve your reputation) Site say to me, that i must have 15 reputation to vote.